# What is the total pressure of an air stream in motion?

Tags: aerodynamics

This question is from a French aeronautics exam so I translated as best I can but I suck at these terms in English. Anyways, can someone please explain this question to me because I'm just really confused by other explanations.

In an air stream in motion, the total pressure is equal to:

```
- difference between dynamic pressure and static pressure.
- sum of dynamic and static pressures.
- difference between atmospheric pressure and dynamic pressure.
- sum of static and atmospheric pressures.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [total pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_pressure) assumes that the is an isentropic evolution from air in movement up to an static state. The total pressure is the pressure at such state.

The way to compute this "made up" variable you need to compute the static pressure and the dynamic pressure (driven by the air speed).

So the answer is:

- the sum of the dynamic and static pressure

But remind that is not "a real property" but more a way to measure the maximum pressure that can be achieved from a fluid in movement without adding extra energy.